# Restart linux kernel NFS lockd

Tags: linux, nfs

Hi is there a way to restart the lockd kernel thread (NFS lock manager)? There were some file locking requests which went wrong and since then it consumes about 50% of CPU. The processes requiring those locks are killed.

Also enabling NLM debug shows me this in logs:

```
Jan 14 16:50:27 backend2 kernel: [677200.130257] lockd: unlock failed (err = 13)
Jan 14 16:50:27 backend2 kernel: [677200.130260] lockd: request from 127.0.0.1, port=789
Jan 14 16:50:27 backend2 kernel: [677200.130262] lockd: rebind host localhost
```

Comment: Nevermind. I have mounted a gluster expoted volume without  nolock option.